# Filter list data based on current user login in SharePoint2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two working codes which I want to merge. So far the attempts are unsuccessful.

The first piece is to identify the current user in SharePoint:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
var context = null;
var web = null;
var currentUser = null;
    function getWebUserData() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
 currentUser.retrieve();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));

    }
    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
        var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
                alert('Login Name:' + userObject.get_loginName());
    }

    function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }</script>
```

This is the second piece which displays the list data in Web-part:

```
<script src="/sites/SiteName/SitePages/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/SiteName/SitePages/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table border="1" align="center" width="90%" id="myHTMLTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="left">
            <td><b>Title</b></td>
            <td><b>Login</b></td>
            <td><b>Price</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
getMyListData() ;
function getMyListData() {
    var method = "GetListItems";                 
    var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                     
    var list = "Products";                      
    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
    var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'  Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>";                       

    $().SPServices
    ({
        operation: method,
        async: false, 
        webURL: webURL,
        listName: list,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
        CAMLQuery: query,                                                                                     
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                var login = $(this).attr("ows_Login");
                var Price =  $(this).attr("ows_Price");
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                 "<td align='left'>"+Title+"</td>" +
                 "<td align='left'>"+Login+"</td>" +
                 "<td align='left'>"+Price+"</td>"  +                                         
                 "</tr>"
                );
            });
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

The reason I want to merge these two pieces is, I have the list with everyone's details including logins. I want to restrict the view to the specific user where one can see only their data based on login filtering in javascript.

I understand that this can be done in sharepoint options however i will have only 5000 entries in a view and i can't increase them because of my org restrictions

Comment: What type of column is `Login`?

Comment: username of the person

Comment: Sorry, I meant is it a "single line of text" or a "person or group"?

Comment: Person or group

Comment: If the records are created by individual users or somehow you can create column extra person column with user details in it,  you can create list view with [Me] filter on it and display the list view instead of creating webpart Ref : http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/10/advanced-sharepoint-view-and-filters/

Answer (score 0):

If "Login" is a Person or Group field, and you want to restrict the data so that the current user can only see records where he is the "Login", and you want to display the data in a web-part then you do not actually need to write any code.

You need to create a view where the filter will be : Login equals [Me]
Then create a list view web part and attach it to that view to show on your page.

I would be very surprised if any organization would disable creation of views especially if it means developers not writing code to achieve something that the product offers OOTB.

Comment: My bad, I have updated it incorrectly. i have an option of creating views however my threshold is 5000 entries and i cannot increase it

Comment: @Sreevastav - Considering that your CamlQuery does not seem to have any limiting factor or paging even that will break if the number of items you are querying is above 5k. Basically what I am trying to say is what you are doing is no different then retrieving all items and then trying to filter on that which well can be done using a simple view. Can you specify the following: 1. How many items are in the list? 2. Is Login an indexed column? If your total items in the list is above 5k then you just need to add "Login" as an indexed column and the view will work.

Comment: If your current number of items is below 5k (which would explain why your code succeeds in retrieving items) and you know that the list will exceed 5k then it will be prudent to make the "Login" field indexed from now. Your code will also stop working as soon as the list exceeds 5k items. Also you can use the following where condition in your CamlQuery for doing a person filter by current logged in user - "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Login' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where>"

Comment: var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'  Ascending='True' /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Login' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

Comment: @Sreevastav could you please respond on if this helped you and mark the answer as accepted if this helped you.